# Bad built-in chain name with iptables-restore

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, centos

I saved my iptable settings on a Ubuntu 11.4 system using

```
iptables-save >filename
```

I then replaced the Ubuntu system with CentOS 6.5 and tried to restore iptables using

```
iptables-restore <filename
```

This resulted in

```
iptables-restore v1.4.7: Can't set policy 'INPUT' on 'ACCEPT' line 4: Bad bilt-in chain name
```

Line 4 is as follows.

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [199972:10416012]
```

In the past I have been able to restore iptables fron Ubuntu systems onto Debian systems but Debian is more closely related to Ubuntu than is CentOS.  With CentOS, would I just need to add the rules manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did

```
iptables-save >iptables.original
```

on my CentOS box and saw that the

```
:INPUT ACCEPT
```

line was not present in iptables.original. So I commented out the line from the file I saved on Ubuntu and

```
iptables-restore <filename
```

no longer gave any error messages. I subsequently did

```
iptables-restore --list-rules
```

and the rules look like the ones that I want.